Torricelli, in his work Opera Geometrica, to what extent did he give the expression known as Torricelli's equation?
I became aware only recently of the content of Torricelli's law (considered to be part of the subject of fluid dynamics), which made me aware that Torricelli's Law and Torricelli's equation are closely related.
(I have known Torricelli's equation for a long time, I just never took a look at the content of Torricelli's law.)
Torricelli's law:
In the idealized case: if you have a column of fluid in some container, and there is an opening through which fluid is squirting out, then the kinetic energy of the squirted fluid is equal to the potential energy corresponding to the height of the fluid column above the opening.
Torricelli's equation:
$s$ position coordinate
$v$ velocity
$a$ acceleration
$2\,a\,\Delta s = v^2 - v_0^2$
In retrospect we see that Torricelli's equation anticipated the work-energy theorem.


Primary source:
Available for viewing/download on the website of the European digital mathematical library:
PDF with scanned pages of Torricelli's Opera Geometrica
(The full book is a 174 MB file)
(De PDF with scans consists of two books, in the sense that after page 243 there is a new title page, and the page numbering starts again with 1.)
The part where Torricelli describes the motion of water being squirted out starts at page 191 of the original page numbering, in a section titled: 'DE MOTU AQUARUM'.
That part of the Opera Geometrica is written in latin. In some of the sentences many of the words have cognates in english, making the sentence fairly readable.
Example:

Si tubus A B convenientis capacitatis, hoc est magna laxitatis, intelligatur semper aquaplenus usque ad libellam A, et perforetur an gusto orificio in B.

For the rest I'm using Google translate.

My request:
I'm looking for an accessible source (not behind paywall) describing in what form Torricelli gave the relation that today is known as 'Torricelli's equation'.


It may well be that later authors have attributed to Torricelli way more than the extent of what Torricelli had actually published.
I'm transcribing the original latin text, running it section by section through Google translate.
But it could be many more pages until I either encounter Torricelli's equation (in some form or another), or reach the end of the discussion of the squirting water.
So I'm hoping that specific research about this is already available, and accessible.

Bistafa in First Theoretical Constructions to the Fluid Mechanics Problem of the Discharge describes what Torricelli stated in De Motu Aquarum in geometric terms using ratios, "that the velocity is proportional to the square root of the height, and that this velocity is the same that a heavy body acquires by falling from a height." I think it is open access.

I find Bistafa's paper linked above to be freely accessible, at least from within the United States. It notes that "In De motu projectorum, Torricelli dedicates a chapter to the motion of water (Torricelli, 1644: pp. 191-203) " Google's scan of Opera Geometrica shows this exactly where Bistafa states. I would suggest reading the two  side by side. Side remark / caveat: When it comes to Latin I have found that Google's translation "skills" are fairly weak.

Some additional sources of historical discussions: Malcherek, A. (2016). History of the Torricelli principle and a new outflow theory. Journal of Hydraulic Engineering, 142(11), 02516004. and Pisano et al (2024) Homage to Evangelista Torricelli’s Opera Geometrica 1644–2024. Springer, though both not freely accessible.

@Conifold Thank you. The Bisfafa paper is sufficient. As was to be expected: Torricelli gave the relation in terms of a ratio. That means in particular that the algebraic form $2,a,s=v^2-v_0^2$ is from a much later date.

@njuffa An advantage of Google Translate (latin-english) is that it is remarkably resilient against transcription errors. Presumably during the deep learning training stage the machine has also been presented with error-containing transcripts that had been well translated. I am of course on the alert for hallucinations. Again: scientific english and scientific latin have many cognates, and I already know what Torricelli wants to convey.
